# How to create different and unique ID for some class in css?

Tags: css, wordpress, html

As the title says I would like to create a unique div ID for some class in css. Here is some examples:

http://prntscr.com/29rom4
These two blocks are using the same class in the wordpress' css. They are both named as td_block4.

http://prntscr.com/29rp81
Now I would like to create a unique div in the css file of the wordpress theme, where I can put a different background for each "block4".

Here is the example of what I actually want to do: prntscr.com/29rpvd (not a perfect improvisation) :)

And... when I put (in example):

```
    .td_block4 {background-color:#000;}
```

...in the css, I get this: prntscr.com/29rqbh , and that's not what I want to get.

I hope I'm clear enough, how can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should provide code, instead of a lot of screenshots and screenshots of code. Provide your affected code in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so we can easily edit it.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your suggestion, can you tell me what exactly you need to know? I have no idea what actually I have to tell to try to fix this problem that I'm trying to fix with days.

Comment: Take a copy of the affected code, what is in your code screenshot, put it into the HTML section of the jsFiddle, put the CSS for `.td_block4` in the CSS section, and then run it, check that it's doing what you're expecting (but not what you're wanting,) Save it and provide us the link.

Comment: Okay, I think that I found what you actually need, I hope this is okay. There we go: http://jsfiddle.net/UpU2q/ So, I hope you will be able to make them with different background colors. Let's say that "СПОРТ" is okay with that black bg. Try to change the other one, so "СПОРТ" and "ЉУБОВ И СЕКС" will be with different background colors. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry that I'm acting like newbie, but after long time looking to solve this problem, I'm totally lost. Thanks to this website and the people inside, I hope that my headache will disappear. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<div>`s are surrounded by some more unique parents, so you can simply do:

```
.span6 .td_block4 { background-color: #f00; }
.span4 .td_block4 { background-color: #000; }
```

Sometimes, it's not about hooking onto a unique element you want, but by finding a way to use its parents to hook onto a common element, differentiated by unique parents.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but on the website I'm working on this didn't fixed the issue. Thanks once again.

Comment: This means your jsFiddle is incorrectly reflecting your site. Do you have a link to your site we can see?

Comment: Sure... let's see like this... http://taratur.com/2013/ the blocks are already with black background.

Comment: So because your `<div>`s in your site are surrounded by other things, and not in the same level, you can't use the 2.1 selector. But you can do it another way. I have updated this answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This fixed it, no more headache. Thanks for your time Sir.

Comment: That's alright. Can you accept this answer if you are happy with it?

Comment: So, we have one more, and I hope last problem. span6 is only for the block "ЉУБОВ И СЕКС", and span4 for the rest of them. Is there any way so I'll be able to edit all of them? By the way, the answer is accepted.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure I understand your question. You want to edit all of which columns? I assume they have different code and so you're not getting the effect you want.

Comment: Okay, this is what I meant. You have the link, and with the code you gave me, .span6 I can edit the block "ЉУБОВ И СЕКС". That's okay, we don't have anything to touch here. Now, with the one, .span4 I edit the rest of the blocks: "СПОРТ", "НАУКА И ТЕХНОЛОГИЈА" and the two blocks in the footer, they go under span4. I want to be able to edit each of them, in example with different backgrounds. I was trying but without success.

Comment: Hmm that's going to be tough, you don't have very good hooks on the page. And you're unable to edit any of the HTML?

Comment: Ummm... there is no other way like creating a div/class for each of them ha?

Comment: You can easily get the two columns in the footer, as they have unique identifiers to grab on to, such as `.td-footer-wrap .span4 + .span4 td_block4 { /* here */ }` and `.td-footer-wrap .span4 + .span4 + .span4 td_block4 { /* also here */ }` but as for the other columns in `.td-page-wrap` they're not particularly good. If you can edit the HTML you would be better off doing that. If you can't, then you might have to look at using JS/jQuery to sniff the content, and traverse up the tree to the `.td_block4` to add a class on to it.

Comment: Okay, I will see what I can do. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do that only via javascript.You can attack div data-image's with their background , and on load check it and write some js like ".css('background-image',dataimage)"

Take it easy

Answer (score 0):

Try jquery for this

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.td_block4:first').css('background-color','#000');
});
```

And you can use css for the rest

Comment: Where should I put this jquery if I go for this way, and then continue with the rest in css?

Comment: This jquery will reset the first div to another background. So in CSS you just keep your main background (for example "red" like your visual). Then put this jquery in the html (after include the jquery, of course) and change your wanted background color ("white", I guess).